# How do I create a custom gym environment based on an image?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to create my own gym environment for the A3C algorithm. The custom environment is a simple login form for any site. I want to create an environment from an image. The idea is to take a screenshot of the web page and create an environment from this screenshot for the A3C algorithm. I know the doc and protocol for creating a custom environment. But I don't understand how to create an environment, exactly, based on a screenshot.

If I do so

```
self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

I get a new pic.

Here's the algorithm that I am trying to implement https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfrJu.png

The whole paper is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oenbo13OkGtKX2nTfRi7ggyb520tAu2j/viewusp=sha ing

The algorithm of A3C is here: https://github.com/dgriff777/rl_a3c_pytorch

Comment: I just want to let you know that, if you have a _theoretical_ question about RL topics, [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is the best site to ask it. Not sure if this is a theoretical question tough.

Comment: Could you give some more information about the environment you are trying to create?

Comment: I tried create a simple login form environment.  There should be input text field for password, login and button to sign in. I think that the question isn't right. According to information I've found, I shouldn't  create a new environment from image)  What I try to do: I try to change usual open ai gym environment to a physical website. The idea is: to   make screenshot and  pass to A3C. As output I want to get probability map - (action prob, coordinates of element).  The approach described here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oenbo13OkGtKX2nTfRi7ggyb520tAu2j/view?usp=sharing).